# Generating manifest file by firebase get value null to property `splash_pages`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, manifest, progressive-web-apps, web-manifest

What value should take `splash_pages` property in `manifest.json`?

by default it's `null`

I have used firebase manifest generator and this property get null value, 
I want to know what value should it take?
and is it supported by all browsers or just Chrome

Thnx!